# Latex ClassicThesis - The numbering of the paragraphs does not appear

Tags: latex

I need one more numbered level for my report. I used \paragraph{title} but it only appears without numbering.

In the config file, the paragraph is described as:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
        {\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{0pt}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
```

I believe that the command `\theparagraph` is responsible for the numbering. Why doesn't it appear?

I searched the net for answers and tried the following commands (at once) before the beginning of the document:

- `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\paragraphnumdepth}`
- Replace the previous command to get rid of run-in with:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}
        {\relax}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\theparagraph}}}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}
```

- `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}`

I put the last two commands in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

The paragraph name appears like the section names now, but still no numbers. Any ideas? Here is a small example that works because I didn't include the classicthesis config files.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\paragraphnumdepth}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chapitre}
    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Première sous-partie}
    \subsubsection{Un cran en dessous}
    \paragraph{Paragraphe with number: what I would like in my report}  
     Functional here because the problem clearly comes from the two classicthesis config files... 

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Like I said I don't see how I can make a minimal example since classicthesis contains 2 config files that I cannot include. The problem is probably included in these config files but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Why not? If they are too big to include in the question, you could share them via pastebin.com, github or similar sites.

Comment: I added a small example, but it is working since I cannot include the classicthesis config files. At least this proves that it comes from these two missing files. Maybe someone will have an idea of what is blocking the numbering.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that.